# Referring to a gerund with a pronoun

Tags: pronouns, gerunds

Is it considered grammatical to refer to a gerund in the subject position with the pronoun "it"?
Example:

> **Visiting** a dentist regularly is recommended as **it** can contribute to overall health.

Comment: Fishing is permitted here, isn't it?

Comment: @GEdgar It is clear that that is not the *it* that you think it is.

Answer (score 6):

Sure. Using the pronoun *it* there is perfectly grammatical.

Answer (score 5):

Gerunds are words derived from verbs that are used as nouns; they can be used as subject of a sentence, and (as with every noun) you can replace them with pronouns.

Comment: Gerunds aren't used as nouns though. Gerunds can take subjects and objects. In this example, the gerund *visiting* has the object *the dentist*. If I replace the gerund with a noun, the result is ungrammatical: *Visitation a dentist regularly is recommended.*

Comment: @morphail Actually, I would not use _visitation_ because it means " an official or formal visit." The fact gerunds function as nouns doesn't mean you can always replace them with another noun.

Comment: @kiamlaluno My point is that a nouns and gerunds occupy certain syntactic slots. You can't put a noun in the slot that a gerund occupies. If gerunds were nouns, then I should be able to replace them with other nouns. For instance, _dentist_ is a noun, and I can replace it with another noun: _Visiting a house regularly is recommended._ The sentence might not make sense, but it is grammatical because the noun is in the right place. But if I replace _visiting_ with a noun, then the result is ungrammatical: _Visitation a dentist regularly is recommended._ A gerund is not a noun.

Comment: @morphail I didn't write that a gerund is a noun; I wrote that gerunds function as nouns (or they are used as nouns). The fact you cannot always replace a gerund with a noun is not different from the fact you cannot always replace a noun with another noun. Take as example "the lions roar"; _lions_ is a noun, but you cannot replace it with _lambs_, and obtain "the lambs roar."

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes you can. _The lambs roar_ is a grammatical sentence. We have a noun, _lambs_, preceding the verb _roar_ and following the determiner _the_. But replacing a gerund with a noun often results in an ungrammatical sentence, as in my example. In my example, we have the noun phrase _a dentist_ immediately following the noun _visitation_. This is not grammatical; we can't stick 2 noun phrases together like this. As far as I can see, there's no difference between saying something functions as a noun or is used as a noun, and saying it is a noun.

Comment: There is a difference; it's the same difference that there is between saying that something is a weapon, and something can be used as weapon.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1594/discussion-between-morphail-and-kiamlaluno)